# Split: A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a super simple formula. The problem is that sometimes the data doesn't have a second value, or sometimes the value is blank.

```
Split ({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}," ")[2]

ID
111 222
123

123 222
```

I was thinking if I could come up with some logic to figure out whether the string has multiple value's it would solve my problem, but haven't quiet found what I'm looking for:

```
If {PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID} = SingleOrBlankString then 
{PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID} else
Split ({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}," ")[2]
```

Better Example Data:

```
3011111*42011111111
2711 00291111111

711111//12111111111
/J1111 69111111111
170111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string can contain a maximum of two values, separated by a `space`, then you can check if the string contains a `space` using the `InStr` function:

```
If InStr({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, " ") > 0 Then
    {PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}
Else
    Split ({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}," ")[2]
```

If there can be multiple spaces between the parts you can use following formulas to get the values:

**Left part:**

This function returns the left part of the string until the first space.

```
If InStr({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, " ") > 0 Then
    Left({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, InStr({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, " "))
```

**Right part:**

This function returns the right part of the string after the last space.

- The `InStrRev`-function returns the position of the last space because it searches the string backwards.
- The `Len`-function returns the length of the string.
- [length] - [position of last space] = [length of the right part]

```
If InStr({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, " ") > 0 Then
    Right({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, Len({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}) - InStrRev(testString, " "))
```

Comment: Must be hidden spaces in the data after the numbers. I raised the > 0 to 10 and some values still weren't split. My last iteration of the formula is: if isnull({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}) then "" else if {PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID} = ""  then "" else Split({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}," ")[2]

Comment: Can you show an example-value of the `{PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}`-column?

Comment: added above, can't give exact as it is sensitive data, but I included all types of variables I see in the data. (Anything with a 1 can be any character)

Comment: Please add the sample data to your question, not to the answer.

Comment: This seems to be working without issue, but I don't fully understand it. Any possibility you could break it down so I can better comprehend. (Right Part)

Comment: @Charles Added an explanation

Comment: Here is the final formula used if anyone ever runs into this probem: If InStr({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, " ") > 0 Then
    Right({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, Len({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}) - InStrRev({PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}, " ")) else {PO_RECEIVE.VENDOR_LOT_ID}